# Azure Speaker Recognition sample gives unauthorized error

Tags: azure, speech-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

Trying to run [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/get-started-speaker-recognition?tabs=script&pivots=programming-language-csharp) sample in msdn with C# and Java, but gets below error.

[image]

I have paid subscription for speech service and able to get get speech to text using same subscription key and region as given in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/troubleshooting?tabs=powershell#validate-an-authorization-token).

I am working on Windows 11, not sure speech SDK has any dependency on OS version. Anyone facing same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to run the speaker recognition sample with out an issue, You can use the latest speech SDK version 1.26.0.

[image]